# How to compare value with predicate criteria builder

Tags: java, spring-boot, predicate, predicatebuilder

I have an searchValue, inputted by user, and I want to find all the customers that have similar name, email, username, phone,... etc. like it. I'm using the Specifications to create a spec then inject it into repository file
This is the Entity

```
public class DealRequestEntity {
    private long id;
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, optional = false)
    @JoinColumn(name = "customer_id", referencedColumnName = "id")
    private CustomerEntity customer;
}
```

And the Specifications

```
public class DealRequestSpecifications {

    public static Specification<DealRequestEntity> hasSearchValue(String searchValue) {
        return new Specification<DealRequestEntity>() {
            public Predicate toPredicate(Root<DealRequestEntity> root, CriteriaQuery<?> query,
                    CriteriaBuilder builder) {
                return builder.like(builder.lower(root.get("customer").get("name")), searchValue.toLowerCase());
            }
        };
    }
}
```

And the get("name") always warning error there. So what is the right keyword that I can research for this?

I tried to get("customer").get("name") but it didn't work

Comment: And the warning you get is?

Comment: You are trying to use like operator builder.like(builder.lower(root.get("customer").get("name")), searchValue.toLowerCase()); use % in the query parameter and try.

Answer (score 0):

I found the way, after 2 days of roaming around.

```
public static Specification<DealRequestEntity> hasSearchValue(String searchValue) {
    return (root, query, builder) -> {
        Join<DealRequestEntity, CustomerEntity> customerJoin = root.join("customer");
        return builder.or(
                builder.like(builder.lower(customerJoin.get("name")), "%" + searchValue.toLowerCase() + "%"),
                builder.like(builder.lower(customerJoin.get("username")), "%" + searchValue.toLowerCase() + "%"),
                builder.like(builder.lower(customerJoin.get("email")), "%" + searchValue.toLowerCase() + "%"),
                builder.like(builder.lower(customerJoin.get("phone")), "%" + searchValue.toLowerCase() + "%"));
    };
}
```